# Keeping track of smallest or largest

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop

I'm currently working on a drill from stroustrups book. The drill requires that you read a double each time through a loop and use 2 variables to keep track of the smallest and largest values read so far. Here's my attempt, but it doesn't work quite so well at the moment. Any help will be appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;

int main()
{
    double d = 0;
    double smallest = 0;
    double largest = 0;

    while (cin >> d)
    {

        if (d > largest)
        {
            largest = d;
             cout << largest << " is the largest value yet" 
<< '\n';

        }
        else if (d < largest)
        {
        smallest = d;
        cout << smallest << " is the smallest value yet" 
<< '\n';
        }
        else
        continue;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does "doesn't work quite so well" mean? How does it work exactly? What is the output you get, and for what input?

Comment: Language tag please

Comment: Did you mean to write `else if (d < smallest)` instead of `else if (d < largest)`?

Comment: You need a [mcve]. What is not working?

Comment: Sorry. If I read in 1, that becomes the largest value. If I then read in 71, that becomes the largest value. If I then read in 41, this becomes the smallest value. But that isn't correct and not sure how to fix that problem

Comment: @Njgardner90 [C++ can be fun](https://www.ideone.com/kRnhoV).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, best solution!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your issue is that you have 0 as the minimum to start. Which, well, is the minimum you could ever have.  Set it to the maximum possible double value.  Something like this should work for you.

I also removed your else, because your first number should be the largest and smallest, right?

You also had `largest` in your `smallest` if statement.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double d = 0;
    double smallest = DBL_MAX;
    double largest = -DBL_MAX;

    while (cin >> d)
    {
        if (d > largest)
        {
            largest = d;

            cout << largest << " is the largest value yet\n\r";

        }

        if (d < smallest)
        {
            smallest = d;

            cout << smallest << " is the smallest value yet\n\r";
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to keep your else in there, the solution is almost the same, but we're basically just hiding that the first pass sets both to the same value.  This doesn't make sense to me, but here you have it.  This is how you will solve your problem with the 1, 71, 41 example, where 41 was set to the smallest number in your code.  It's incorrect because it wasn't setting 1 to both smallest and largest.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double d = 0;
    double smallest = DBL_MAX;
    double largest = -DBL_MAX;
    bool firstPass = true;

    while (cin >> d)
    {
        if (d > largest)
        {
            largest = d;

            cout << largest << " is the largest value yet\n\r";
        }
        else if (d < smallest)
        {
            smallest = d;

            cout << smallest << " is the smallest value yet\n\r";
        }

        if(firstPass) 
        {
            firstPass = false;

            smallest = d;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I edited to fix some other issues.

Comment: So reading the value 72 printed that this was the largest and smallest value.

Comment: @Njgardner90 And what do you think it should have printed instead? What is the largest and what is the smallest number when you have 1 number?

Comment: This will fail if the user only enters negative numbers.  There is no need to set `smallest` and `largest` to any value as they can both be set to the first input.

Comment: Sorry, I removed your else. I just ran it in my IDE and realized you may want to only set the largest value on the first pass. Is that the case? If so I can throw the else back in there.

Comment: @NathanOliver, yes. That is correct. Thanks for that.

Comment: @Killzone Kid The variables smallest and largest are supposed to keep track of the smallest and largest values so far. So if I read in 1, and then 71 - reading in 41 shouldn't print "the smallest value so far" as it currently does. Sorry for not being clear

Comment: @Njgardner90 cannot confirm. 1 -> is both largest and smallest, because only 1 number, 71 -> largest, 41 -> it doesn't print anything for me because it is neither largest nor smallest.

Comment: @Njgardner90, your solution has that else in there. So, it was always setting the first value to the largest, no matter what. Let me know exactly what you want to do with some examples. It's just a logic problem at this point, though. I think this code can get you going.

Comment: Actually, I'm taking the else out again. Unless you always want to set the largest first, no matter what number comes in, it will set both on the first pass.

Comment: @Killzone Kid From my original post, reading in 1 prints "the largest value yet", then reading in 71 reads "the largest value yet" but if I then read in 41, it prints "the smallest value yet"

Comment: @Njgardner90 are we talking about your original post or this solution?

Comment: @Njgardner90, yes, that is because you ALWAYS set the largest number, no matter what number came in, and you had that else in there that skipped the smallest. Do you want to skip the smalest?

Comment: @adpro the problem for me is making sure the smallest number so far is actually the smallest and not just smaller than the largest value that was read previously

Comment: @Njgardner90, if the smallest and largest number are both set on the first number entered, you will always end up with the smallest number being a smaller number than that number if one were entered, and the largest number would only change if a larger number were entered.  The only time a number would go into both smallest and largest is on the first pass.  I don't really understand what you mean by making sure it's not just smaller than the largest value. Once they're both set (to the first value) your smallest will only change when a value is entered that is smaller than smallest.

Comment: @Njgardner90, do you only want to set the largest on the first path? Removing that else seems to fix your problem with 1, 71, 41 entered. 1 will be the smallest, and 71 will be the largest.  Can they not be the same ever?  That would be the question to ask. My solution solves your problem. If you need that else in there for some reason, please let me know why.

Comment: @adpro Yeah, the program has to keep track of the smallest value so far, and the largest. So no number entered could be smaller than the smallest and vice versa. It's a bit hard to explain. I just want to get past this drills part from Bjarne stroustrups book!

Comment: @adpro looks like the second solution you put in works. Thank you :)

Comment: @Njgardner90, no problem.

Answer (score -2):

```
else if (d < largest)
```

should be

```
else if (d < smallest)
```

and

```
 double smallest = 0;
```

should be

```
  double smallest = 1000000; // or some very large number
```

Comment: Consider using [`std::numeric_limits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits) when you need "very large" or "very small" values instead of arbitrary values.

Comment: This also doesn't solve the issue he was having with the smallest being set after the largest